# Failed to write data to influxDB through Shell script

Tags: shell, udp, influxdb

Config an UDP port 8089 in /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf:

```
[[udp]]
 enabled = true
 bind-address = "0.0.0.0:8089"
 database = "testdb"
 retention-policy = ""
```

Started InfluxDB with port 8089

```
[udp] 2016/06/29 23:17:59 Started listening on UDP: 0.0.0.0:8089
```

Tried to write metric data in a Shell script:

```
 HOST_OR_IP_OF_INFLUXDB_SERVER=my_ip
 PORT=8089

 # Refer to line protocol:
 # https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.9/write_protocols/line/
 echo "temperature,machine=unit42,type=assembly internal=32 1434055562000000035" | nc -v -u -w 1 $HOST_OR_IP_OF_INFLUXDB_SERVER $PORT
```

InfluxDB server showed error message:

```
[udp] 2016/06/29 23:52:18 Failed to parse points: unable to parse 'X': missing fields
[udp] 2016/06/29 23:52:18 Failed to parse points: unable to parse 'X': missing fields
[udp] 2016/06/29 23:52:18 Failed to parse points: unable to parse 'X': missing fields
[udp] 2016/06/29 23:52:18 Failed to parse points: unable to parse 'X': missing fields
```

Seems the data sent to server satisfies the line protocol of InfluxDB, can anyone give any clue on the problem? Thanks.

Comment: did you try using the documented connections via `curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb' --data-binary ....` from https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/guides/writing_data/ ? If that works, then it is something about using `nc`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks for your comments. I notice the data sent through UDP port 8089 has been stored in InfluxDB. This might be a defect of InfluxDB server.

Comment: You might want to look thru the developer forums for this project and see if there are any related posts with solutions or work-arounds. If not, post a copy/pasted-able test case to their bugs forum. OR determine that you need to try another approach. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In Bash one can simply skip the `nc`:

```
echo -n "temperature,machine=unit42,type=assembly internal=32 1434055562000000035" \
> /dev/udp/$HOST_OR_IP_OF_INFLUXDB_SERVER/$PORT
```